# Javascript Encode result after fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

So i need to encode characters after fetch and when i  encoded show as text. here is my code

```
 fetch('URL', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'text/xml',
      },
    })
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(data => {
       console.log(result)
    })
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

its working fine but there are bad characters.

This is how can i encode

```
      buf = iconv.encode("PosteÄľ roĹˇtovĂˇ", 'win1250');
      str = iconv.decode(Buffer.from(buf), 'utf-8');
      console.log(str)  // Posteľ roštová
```

so how can i do it in react native

Comment: Please add result from fetch.

Comment: This is the result Nebol n�jden� �iadny s�bor pre spracovanie.